# OpenModelica and dynamic optmization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, modelica, openmodelica

I want to test dynamic optimization methods within OpenModelica (the builtin with ADOL-C and the CasADi based). Are there somewhere more information about different options  (e.g. change the number of finite elements for collocation, the number of collocation points in each element, change the linear Solver for IPOPT to MA 57). I read the user guide and the listed papers on their homepage, but there are limited information.

Furthermore, is it posible to set up and run optimizations via  Python Interface and/or PySimulator?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The ADOL-C implimentation is only awiable on
https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/browser/branches/newadolc
so you will need build it by your self

The native builtin danamic optimization is part of the master and include in each https://openmodelica.org/download/nightlybuildsdownload  build.

If you build openmodelica with MA57 you can set the linear solver with
simulation flag -ls-ipopt
https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/v1.9.5/simulationflags.html#simflag-ls-ipopt
Note: You will need build ipopt with MA57 by your selfs. OpenModeica has no licence for MA57.

Good news: In the nightly-build you can set the number of  collocation points with 
https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/v1.9.5/simulationflags.html#simflag-optimizernp
and 
number of finite elements  is numberOfIntervalls.

for more informations see.:
https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/optimization.html